# Loading ISSUE in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, rake

I'm facing a problem with Loading a Constant in Rails console (rails console). Here how my structure look like this

```
- app
   - controllers
   - models 
     - earning
        - daily_earning.rb
        - monthly_earning.rb
        - weekly_earning.rb
        - yearly_earning.rb
   - views
```

Some more information

I also have a rake which look like this

```
namespace :past_days do
  desc "Past 7 Days Earning"
  task :earning => :environment do
    puts $:.select { |i| i=~ /models/ }.to_yaml
    7.downto(1).each do |i|
      start_date = i.days.ago.beginning_of_day
      puts "====== Dumping past #{start_date.strftime('%A')} earning ====="
      end_date = start_date.end_of_day
      Performer.top_daily_earners(start_date,end_date)
      puts "====== Dumped #{start_date.strftime('%A')} earning !!! ======="
      puts
    end 
  end
end
```

And the `top_daily_earners` method look like this If you check this `@klass = DailyEarning`

```
def top_daily_earners(start_date=nil,end_date=nil)
  unless start_date or end_date
    date = 1.day.ago
    @start_date,@end_date = date.beginning_of_day,date.end_of_day
  end
  if start_date and end_date
    @start_date,@end_date = start_date,end_date
  end
  @klass = DailyEarning
  @earning_performers  = retrieve_earnings
  puts "COUNT -----"
  puts @earning_performers.count 
  puts ""
  store_earning
end
```

#### Question :

Now when I run rake task `bundle exec rake past_days:earning` (Rake run without any error) all work fine but when I run this

`rails console` see attach screenshot

[image]

I get errors `NameError: uninitialized constant DailyEarning` and I have manually require the file as can be seen the above screenshot

So the POINT of all the above **question** is why the error on `rails console` **(NameError: uninitialized constant DailyEarning)**  and why not the error in 
rake task

## Attaching DailyEarning Code based on @dtt comment

```
puts 'DailyEarning'
class DailyEarning
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in session: "writeable"
  field :performer_id, :type => Integer
  field :user_id,:type => Integer
  field :stage_name,:type => String
  field :full_name,:type => String
  field :start_date,:type => DateTime
  field :end_date,:type => DateTime
  field :amount,:type => BigDecimal
  before_create :other_details
  ## Please avoid using default scope because it AFAIK it make the date parameter as static 

  class << self
    def default_scoping
      where(:start_date.gte => 1.day.ago.beginning_of_day).and(:end_date.lte => 1.day.ago.end_of_day)
    end
  end

  private
  def other_details
    ## Fetch from Mongo Instead of Mysql to avoid the slow sql query
    performer_source = PerformerSource.where(performer_id: performer_id).only([:stage_name,:user_id]).first
    self.user_id = performer_source.user_id
    self.stage_name = self.stage_name
    #self.full_name  = self.full_name
  end  
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the DailyEarning model so I can see how it is defined?

Comment: Done hope it help you I taught it not required anyway hence did not attach it question before :(

Comment: When you do a `rails s`, the error is shown in the log too?

Comment: @MurifoX Nope no error :)

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that to autoload a model in a folder you would need to namespace it:

to autoload the model in app/models/earning/daily_earning.rb

```
class Earning::DailyEarning

end
```

it may be that instead you could use:

```
module Earning
  class DailyEarning
  end
end
```

Comment: That would be my guess too.

Comment: That is when you need scoping rails `autoload` app directory it would work without this as well just the way it working for rake explicitly mention in my question

Comment: Ok - if you tried it and it didn't work, do post the fix when you find it